# How do I sort a faceted bar plot on the values in one facet?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to order the bars of a vertically facetted bar plot (3 facets) based on the values of one of the facets. Specifically, I want bars in the leftmost panel sorted by decreasing value. My data is based on multi- period fund returns. A period length is a facet; the list of ticker symbols spans all facets. I've found many similar examples, but I can't get the reordering of the x axis labels to work correctly. I'm using the code below on a much longer list of stock symbols, but this should be a working example:

```
require('ggplot2')
require('reshape2')
require('tseries')

symbs = c("XLE", "XLV", "XLK", "XLB", "SPY")
desc = c("Energy", "HealthCare", "Tech", "Materials", "S&P")
data = cbind(symbs, desc)

indexTickers = data[,1]
indexNames = data[,2]

latestDate =Sys.Date()

dailyPrices = lapply(indexTickers, function(ticker) get.hist.quote(instrument= ticker, start = "2012-01-01", 
                    end = latestDate, quote="Close", provider = "yahoo", origin="1970-01-01", compression = "d", retclass="zoo"))
perf5Day = lapply(dailyPrices, function(x){(x-lag(x,k=-5))/lag(x,k=-5)})
perf20Day = lapply(dailyPrices, function(x){(x-lag(x,k=-20))/lag(x,k=-20)})
perf60Day = lapply(dailyPrices, function(x){(x-lag(x,k=-60))/lag(x,k=-60)})

names(perf5Day) = indexTickers
names(perf20Day) = indexTickers
names(perf60Day) = indexTickers

perfsMerged = lapply(indexTickers, function(spdr){merge(perf5Day[[spdr]],perf20Day[[spdr]],perf60Day[[spdr]])})
perfNames = c('1Week','1Month','3Month')
perfsMerged = lapply(perfsMerged, function(x){
  names(x)=perfNames
  return(x)
})

latestDataPoints = t(sapply(perfsMerged, function(x){return(x[nrow(x)])}))

namesAndTickers = paste(indexNames, paste(' (',indexTickers,')',sep=''), sep='')

latestDataPoints = data.frame(cbind(namesAndTickers,latestDataPoints))

latestDataPoints[2:4] <- lapply( latestDataPoints[2:4], function(x) 
  as.numeric(as.character(x)))

names(latestDataPoints) = c('Ticker','5 Day','20 Day','60 Day')

drm = melt(latestDataPoints, id.vars=c('Ticker'))
posNeg =  ifelse(drm$value >= 0, 'pos','neg')

pcts = paste(round(100*drm$value, 2), "%", sep="")
drm = cbind(drm, posNeg, pcts)
names(drm) = c('Ticker','Period','Value','Sign','Pct')

ordered = drm[drm$Period=="5 Day",]
ordered = ordered[order(-ordered$Value),]
orderedSymbs = ordered$Ticker
orderedSymbs = c(orderedSymbs, orderedSymbs, orderedSymbs)

p = ggplot(drm, aes(x=reorder(Ticker, orderedSymbs),y=Value,fill=Sign)) + geom_bar(stat='identity') + facet_grid(. ~ Period,scales='free_y') + 
  coord_flip() + scale_fill_manual(values=c('pos'='darkgreen','neg'='red'),guide=FALSE) +
  ggtitle("Performances of Top Etfs by Trading Volume")

p = p + theme(plot.title = element_text(vjust = 2, size=rel(1.8), 
              face="bold"), axis.text.x=element_text(color='orangered4',size=rel(1.2)), 
              axis.text.y=element_text(color='orangered4',size=rel(1.2)), axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
              axis.title.y = element_blank(), strip.text.x = element_text(size=rel(1.2)))

p
```

[image]

Comment: It may be more tempting to help you if you `dput` a minimal sample of the data frame used in `ggplot` and remove all code related to data preparation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working version.
Besides some cosmetic changes to the code (that I usually use), the only major change was related to rearranging the factors before going into the ggplot.
Hope this helps

```
require('ggplot2')
require('reshape2')
require('tseries')

symbs = c("XLE", "XLV", "XLK", "XLB", "SPY")
desc = c("Energy", "HealthCare", "Tech", "Materials", "S&P")
data = cbind(symbs, desc)

indexTickers = data[,1]
indexNames = data[,2]

latestDate =Sys.Date()

dailyPrices = lapply(indexTickers, function(ticker) get.hist.quote(instrument= ticker, start = "2012-01-01", 
                                                                   end = latestDate, quote="Close", provider = "yahoo", origin="1970-01-01", compression = "d", retclass="zoo"))
perf5Day = lapply(dailyPrices, function(x){(x-lag(x,k=-5))/lag(x,k=-5)})
perf20Day = lapply(dailyPrices, function(x){(x-lag(x,k=-20))/lag(x,k=-20)})
perf60Day = lapply(dailyPrices, function(x){(x-lag(x,k=-60))/lag(x,k=-60)})

names(perf5Day) = indexTickers
names(perf20Day) = indexTickers
names(perf60Day) = indexTickers

perfsMerged = lapply(indexTickers, function(spdr){merge(perf5Day[[spdr]],perf20Day[[spdr]],perf60Day[[spdr]])})
perfNames = c('1Week','1Month','3Month')
perfsMerged = lapply(perfsMerged, function(x){
  names(x)=perfNames
  return(x)
})

latestDataPoints = t(sapply(perfsMerged, function(x){return(x[nrow(x)])}))

namesAndTickers = paste(indexNames, paste(' (',indexTickers,')',sep=''), sep='')

latestDataPoints = data.frame(cbind(namesAndTickers,latestDataPoints))

latestDataPoints[2:4] <- lapply( latestDataPoints[2:4], function(x) 
  as.numeric(as.character(x)))

names(latestDataPoints) = c('Ticker','5 Day','20 Day','60 Day')

drm = melt(latestDataPoints, id.vars=c('Ticker'))
posNeg =  ifelse(drm$value >= 0, 'pos','neg')

pcts = paste(round(100*drm$value, 2), "%", sep="")
drm = cbind(drm, posNeg, pcts)
names(drm) = c('Ticker','Period','Value','Sign','Pct')

ordered = drm[drm$Period=="5 Day",]
ordered = ordered[order(-ordered$Value),]
orderedSymbs = ordered$Ticker
```

Here is the change

```
# commented out this
# orderedSymbs = c(orderedSymbs, orderedSymbs, orderedSymbs)
# added this line, see http://www.r-bloggers.com/reorder-factor-levels-2/ for details
drm$Ticker = factor(drm$Ticker, levels(drm$Ticker)[as.numeric(orderedSymbs)])
```

And some minor modifications here

```
p = ggplot(drm, 
           aes(x=Ticker,
           y=Value,fill=Sign)
)

p = p + geom_bar(stat='identity') + facet_grid(. ~ Period,scales='free_y') 
p = p + coord_flip() + scale_fill_manual(values=c('pos'='darkgreen','neg'='red'),guide=FALSE) 
p = p + ggtitle("Performances of Top Etfs by Trading Volume")

p = p + theme(plot.title = element_text(vjust = 2, size=rel(1.8), face="bold"), axis.text.x=element_text(color='orangered4',size=rel(1.2)), axis.text.y=element_text(color='orangered4',size=rel(1.2)), axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank(), strip.text.x = element_text(size=rel(1.2)))
print(p)
```

[image: The modified plot, with the x-axis values ordered as desired by the OP]

Comment: @StatsViaCsh: Is this solution what you had in mind? Would love to geht feedback!